# Filter tcpdump output (PCAP)

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking

The following is the output from my PCAP file.

```
20:02:52.306161 192.162.70.150.58078 > 192.179.91.61.1194: P 635362993:635363048(55) ack 2046024708 win 4373 <nop,nop,timestamp 52993632 1059054949> (DF)
20:02:52.532863 192.179.91.61.1194 > 192.162.70.150.58078: . ack 55 win 32038 <nop,nop,timestamp 1059062357 52993632> (DF)
20:02:53.157004 802.1d unknown version
20:02:54.759542 arp who-has 192.168.70.34 tell 192.168.70.1
20:02:55.156980 802.1d unknown version
20:02:55.759507 arp who-has 192.168.70.6 tell 192.168.70.1
20:02:55.759540 arp who-has 192.168.70.105 tell 192.168.70.1
20:02:56.148167 192.179.91.61.1194 > 192.168.70.150.58078: P 1:56(55) ack 55 win 32038 <nop,nop,timestamp 1059065972 52993632> (DF)
20:02:56.148258 192.168.70.150.58078 > 192.179.91.61.1194: . ack 56 win 4373 <nop,nop,timestamp 52994592 1059065972> (DF)
```

Is there a way to filter out the contents in following pattern

```
Timestamp | source IP | source Port | destination IP | destination port | protocol | packet size
```

Available commands: `tcpdump`, `tcpslice`, `tcpstat`, `tcpprof`, `tcpparse`

Comment: I would suggest [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html#e-field) (or even Wireshark if you want a GUI for working with your pcap files)

Comment: Or, from another angle, is there a specific reason why there is a rather limited set of "available commands"?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot install any other tools/commands, thats why I have listed down the available commands that can be used.

Comment: Ok. Just to confirm that this is not a matter of confusion regarding the workflow: if this is about something like troubleshooting an issue in a production environment, I am by no means suggesting that you start installing stuff in that environment, rather that you analyze the pcap files elsewhere (eg your workstation, where you have better tooling).